# How many squares are of the form $x^3+7x^2-x$?

Tags: number-theory

> How many squares are of the form $x^3+7x^2-x$, where $x$ is a positive integer, that are not multiples of $16$?

Since $x^3+7x^2-x = x(x^2+7x-1)$, we need both $x$ and $x^2+7x-1$ to be perfect squares and so let $x = k^2$, for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ . Then we need $(k^2)^2+7k^2-1 = k^4+7k^2-1$ to be a perfect square that is not a multiple of $16$. How do we do this?

Comment: $k^4+7k^2-1\equiv3$ mod $4$, hence cannot be a square.

Comment: @BarryCipra The best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ovi Why both $x$ and $ x^2+7x-1$ must be a square? Because they are coprime.

From $x^2+7x-1=k^2$ we get $x^2+7x-1-k^2=0$ and the discriminant is $53+4k^2 = m^2 $. From here $53=(m-2k)(m +2k)$ and $53$ is a prime number. It follows $m+2k = 53, m-2k = 1$ and $m=27, k=13$. Therefore $x^2+7x-170=0$ and, from here, $x=10$ but $10$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: Why does the question say "not multiples of $16$"?

Comment: Not sure what's going on here but taking $m = 27$, $k = 13$ yields the unique solution to $m + 2k = 53$, $m - 2k = 1$.

Comment: @RobertLewis Right, I miscalculated, see the updated answer

Comment: Strictly spaking, we have a solution $m=27, k=13$.  But the corresponding positive root $x=10$ fails to be a perfect square factor.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Right

Comment: Would you mind explaining why does that quadratic have to be a square? I see it the reason the OP gave, but just thinking about the prime factorizations, it doesn't seem clear why that has to be the case.

Comment: @Ovi Because $x, x^2+7x-1$ are coprime.